# Neuroph NEAT preview XOR not training

Tags: java, neural-network

Neuroph released a preview for a NEAT implementation (https://sourceforge.net/projects/neuroph/files/NEAT-preview/). I wanted to try to use it to create an XOR gate (a common thing to try). But for some reason, it's not working. This is the code I used:

First I created the properties:

```
SimpleNeatParameters params = new SimpleNeatParameters();
params.setFitnessFunction(new Fitness());
params.setPopulationSize(150);
params.setMaximumFitness(16);
params.setMaximumGenerations(100);
```

Fitness gives a double value for how well it scored like this:

```
net.setInput(0, 0);
net.calculate();
fitness += (1 - net.getOutput().get(0)) * 4;

net.setInput(1, 0);
net.calculate();
fitness +=  net.getOutput().get(0) * 4;
```

and so on. The idea is if you got it right, you'd be awarded more, to a maximum of four.

Then the input genes:

```
NeuronGene inputOne = new NeuronGene(NeuronType.INPUT, params);
NeuronGene inputTwo = new NeuronGene(NeuronType.INPUT, params);
NeuronGene output = new NeuronGene(NeuronType.OUTPUT, params);
```

Then told it to evolve:

```
Evolver e = Evolver.createNew(params, Arrays.asList(inputOne, inputTwo), Arrays.asList(output));
Organism best = e.evolve();

NeuralNetwork nn = params.getNeuralNetworkBuilder().createNeuralNetwork(best);
```

Then tried it out and I got these results:

```
0, 0: 0.6129870845620041
1, 0: 0.6492975506882983
0, 1: 0.6527754436728792
1, 1: 0.6530807065677073
```

So what's happening? I tried increasing the population, the terminal generation, but nothing works. Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert on Neuroph but maybe it's one of these:

1. Have you set a Selector?

   ```
   NaturalSelectionOrganismSelector selector = new NaturalSelectionOrganismSelector();
   selector.setKillUnproductiveSpecies(true);
   params.setOrganismSelector(selector);
   ```
2. In the example xor test, they square the error. I don't see why that should cause Problems, but who knows?
3. They also reset the neural Network on each call of the Fitness Function.

Comment: Sadly, none of them worked. I tried a selector (the population size didn't change in the log), I squared the result and nothing happened. I also tried reseting it, and that didn't work either. I looked up what .reset() did in the java doc and it looked like it was needed so thanks for that.

Comment: Just to be sure; you have `Fitness extends AbstractFitnessFunction` and your function which calculates the fitness is `evaluate(Organism o, NeuralNetwork nn)`? @NathanWood

Comment: Yes. To be sure, I did some digging in the java doc and found XorFitnessFunction,  a test they made. I had the same problems. Now we know that the error can't be from the fitness function.

Comment: Do you have a speciator? `DynamicThresholdSpeciator speciator = new DynamicThresholdSpeciator();        speciator.setMaxSpecies(4);                   params.setSpeciator(speciator);`

Comment: No, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: Nvm. I think I just wasn't prepared for how long it would take. I used the code in XorExperiment and it worked. I got the results 0.02653836298193064
0.9904104847543085
0.9849212265318241
0.011173404876806991

Comment: Alright then; too bad :/
It's annoying that there is no good documentation for the use of NEAT.
Good luck with whatever you are doing @NathanWood